# Finding Points On a Circle.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, circles

Hello everyone I have 2 points A and B.

And I have to proof that for all X points for them 
$\frac{AX}{BX} = 3$ they are on a one circle.

I tried to convert the equation to something like $x^2 + y^2 = 3$

and calculate the length of AX and BX and place in the equation but I didn't success.

Comment: Just let $X=(x,y)$, $A=(a_1,a_2)$ and $B=(b_1,b_2)$. Write out the given condition. What do you get?

Comment: I did it and I get $\frac{\sqrt{(a_1-x)^2 + (a_2 -y)^2}}{\sqrt{(b_1-x)^2 + (b_2 -y)^2}} = 3$

Comment: Don't take square-roots; bring all coefficients of like terms (like $x^2,x,y^2,y$) together.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently,

$$AX^2=9BX^2$$ is

$$(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2=9((x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2)$$

or

$$x^2-\frac{9x_B-x_A}4x+\frac{9x_B^2-x_A^2}8+y^2-\frac{9y_B-y_A}4y+\frac{9y_B^2-y_A^2}8=0,$$

which is the equation of a circle.

Comment: Thank you very much!!